# Getting my old files back after installing ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, 17.10

During the GUI Ubuntu installation it is written that I could get my partitions back if I'm creating a new one hosting Ubuntu on a disk with already existing data, how can I do that ?

> "You have selected an entire device to partition, if you proceed with
>   creating a new partition table on the device, then all current
>   partitions will be removed. >> Note that you will be able to undo this
>   operation later if you wish. <<

Note that I strangely doesn't have access to my old files from Ubuntu.

Comment: What documentation were you following?

Comment: None... Hopefully I had a backup for my data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All current partitions were removed and yes you can undo that operation later if you wish. The next screen informs you that the partitions will be formatted. I hate to tell you but your data is gone.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully I did a copy of my data on another drive

Comment: What is your backup tool

Comment: There wasn't any OS on it, it was simply some files, so I did a simple copy/paste on Windows with TeraCopy